# .htaccess Wordpress Category Redirects Multiple Domains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm running a Wordpress Site with two domains, which share some contents, especially a shop, but have some separate contents which should be reachable with the same Sub-URLs. Right now I have:

```
domain1.com/press/
domain2.com/press2/
```

because I can't create two categories with the same name/permalink. I'd like to have

```
domain2.com/press/
```

showing the contents of the category press2

Is there a way to do this in .htaccess?